# Loading 3d models from web-server in IOS

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm creating a furniture ARKit app and I can't seem to find anything on loading a 3d model from a web server.

I want to have links to the 3d models on my firebase server and parse them in swift. Is this doable, i can't find any frameworks that support it.

Comment: I have downloaded zip files that contain DAE files and decompressed the zip file into the app's sandbox in the document folder & then loaded 3D objects that way.

Comment: @M.Bedi It will be great if you share demo for the public use.

Comment: Actually, I need to update the code I wrote over a year and may re-write it in Swift very soon.  I would be happy to share some code later.

Comment: @M.Bedi Could you please share the code, even the old code?

Answer (score 2):

> i can't find any frameworks that support it

Check out Apples [ModelIO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/).

> The set of supported formats includes Alembic (.abc), Wavefront Object (.obj), Polygon (.ply), and Standard Tessellation Language (.stl). Additional formats may be supported as well.

I have only worked with `.obj` and while it worked is it a little tricky. Neither Apple nor your 3D tool probably support the full standard and ModelIO will not load anything if it has a problem with a tag or property in your `.obj` or `.mtl` file. I had to modify them by hand to get it to work.

Comment: How should I modify the `.obj` before it can be loaded by Model I/O?
My problem is that Model I/O can't load the `.obj` file which is downloaded from the internet.
The `.obj` renders fine if I import it to Xcode directly.

Comment: @Weizhi try to convert the `.obj` in an `.scn` file, in the SceneKit Editor in Xcode select *Editor -> Convert to .scn*

Comment: @Weizhi were you managed to load the remote 3D models successfully? If you did it would be great to hear how you solved it

Comment: @Nativ We use .obj 3d model. It's easy to load the remote model into the scene using Model I/O.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391513-init

Supported object formats: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391813-canimportfileextension

Answer (score -1):

Since your question has the `SceneKit` tag, I would suggest that you build `.scn` files offline and then upload them on your server. Unlike other file formats there won't be any overhead at load time (like converting Model I/O objects to SceneKit objects).